# Running postgres as a service on windows starts and stops immediately

Tags: windows, windows-services

Since I restarted windows to install updates, Postgres stopped starting as a service.  I thought it may be a permissions so I gave everyone the ability to to modify the postgres install folder.  I then tried to run the database using the start and it works.  But when I try and start the service I get the following message: service on local computer started and stopped.

I then tried to re-install Postgres but it got to the end and it was not able to start.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: The postgresql-9.4 - PostgreSQL Server 8.4 service on local computer started and then stopped.  Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

Comment: have you try looking in Services ? type (go to run and type services.msc) loook for postgresql see if the startup type is set to Automatic.

Comment: Yep, it is set as automatic.  I tried to start it and it gave me that error.  I have restarted the box just incase and it give me the same error

Comment: Simple steps how you can debug it: http://sforsuresh.in/windows-service-local-computer-started-stopped/

Comment: event log : FATAL: XX000: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\postgres.exe: could not locate matching postgres executable LOCATION: getInstallationPaths, d:\pginstaller_13.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\postmaster\postmaster.c:1489 any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to completely uninstall Postgres and re-install it.  I made sure I deleted all traces of it from the disk before re-installing.  That seemed to be the only way to get it working.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on v9.4

I found that deleting `c:\Program Files(x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\data\postmaster.pid` and `\postmaster.opts` then restarting the service resolves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Never do anything drastic like uninstalling and reinstalling without checking the error logs:

(Windows) C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL<version>\data\log

The problem could be something very simple like (in my case) an ip address in `pg_hba.conf` missing its mask - blindly uninstalling probably wouldn't work in cases like that.

Answer (score 1):

I faced exactly the same issue and a good old fashioned system restart worked for me. So, before trying any of the above solutions, I would recommend restarting your system once.

Comment: Restarting always does it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows and I have noticed that sometimes the logs don't tell you what is wrong. A workaround that I found is:

1. On my system postgres.exe is in "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/bin/postgres.exe". Yours should be in a similar location. You will have to change the 16 to your own PostgreSQL version number.
2. Open CMD and run

```
"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/bin/postgres.exe" "-D" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data"
```

The output will tell you why the program isn't running correctly then you can proceed to fix the issues.

In some cases, you will find that your configuration has some issues and once those are fixed the program should run without any more issues.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting .pid file seems like the way to go.

While I found many people recommending it without actually understanding why, [this](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/troubleshooting.html#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%20puts%20a%20file%20named,pid%20file.) troubleshooting doc from Postgre's doc cleared it up.

Quoting for longevity of the answer:

> **The data directory contains an old postmaster.pid file / The data**
> **directory contains an unreadable postmaster.pid file**
>
> PostgreSQL puts a
> file named postmaster.pid in the data directory to store the process
> id of the PostgreSQL server process. If PostgreSQL crashes, this file
> can contain an old pid that confuses PostgreSQL. You can fix this
> issue by deleting the postmaster.pid file. However, you must make sure
> that PostgreSQL is really not running. Open Activity Monitor and make
> sure that there are no processes named ‘postgres’ or ‘postmaster’.
>
> If you delete the postmaster.pid file while PostgreSQL is running, bad
> things will happen.